# Which lactic acid bacteria are Homofermentative (or Heterofermentative)

Tags: fermentation, sugar, lactobacillus

I’m in the process of creating a custom culture, made of lactic acid bacteria, for a artisan yogurt drink and am having a hard time finding information on the metabolic categories of each strain. I was wondering if someone could tell me which Lactobacillus strains are Homofermentative (or Heterofermentative), namely the following strains:

- Lactobacillus Gasseri
- Lactobacillus Fermentum
- Lactobacillus Sakei
- Lactobacillus Salivarius
- Lactobacillus Curvatus
- Lactobacillus Amylovorus
- Lactobacillus Johnsonii
- Lactobacillus Kefiranofaciens
- Lactobacillus Rhamnosus
- Lactobacillus Plantarum
- Lactobacillus Paracasei
- Lactobacillus Helveticus
- Weissella Koreensis
- Weissella Cibaria
- Weissella Cibaria

Answer (score 3):

**This previous question may help you a bit:**

[Is brewers' Lactobacillus heterofermentative or homofermentative?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/is-brewers-lactobacillus-heterofermentative-or-homofermentative)

**This is taken for Wikipedia**

According to metabolism, Lactobacillus species can be divided into three groups:

Obligately homofermentative (Group I) including:

L. acidophilus, L. delbrueckii, L. helveticus, L. salivarius

Facultatively heterofermentative (Group II) including:

L. casei, L. curvatus, L. plantarum, L. sakei

Obligately heterofermentative (Group III) including:

L. brevis, L. buchneri, L. fermentum, L. reuteri

This leaves:

- Lactobacillus Gasseri

"Among these, Lactobacillus gasseri appears to represent the major homofermentative Lactobacillus species that occupies the human GI tract (Mitsuoka, 1992; Kullen et al., 2000). http://genome.jgi-psf.org/lacga/lacga.home.html

- Lactobacillus Amylovorus
- Lactobacillus Johnsonii
- Lactobacillus Kefiranofaciens
- Lactobacillus Rhamnosus
- Lactobacillus Paracasei
- Weissella Koreensis
- Weissella Cibaria

I'll update more with edits as I find it

Answer (score 0):

I found a more specific breakdown of Homofermentative and Heterofermentative bacteria [here](http://lfbisson.ucdavis.edu/PDF/VEN124%20Section%204.pdf)

Homolactic on hexoses:

- L. bavaricus
- L. casei
- L. homohoichii
- L. curvatus
- L. saki
- L. plantarum

Heterolactic on hexoses:

- L. fermentum
- L. brevis
- L. buchneri
- L. fructovorans
- L. hilgardii